# Accessing content of ByteArray without JNI GetByteArrayElements

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I am investigating a more efficient way of accessing the content of a ByteArray through JNI without the ugly GetByteArrayElements.  I am seeking some knowledgeable JNI experts to explain what I am seeing and possibly help with a solution.

**My test function**

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_analyizer(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jbyteArray bytes, jint bytes_len, jlong addr,jint limit) {

    jbyte *elements = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, bytes, false);

    char * e = (void *) elements;
    char * f = (void *) bytes;
    char * o = (void *) (uintptr_t) addr;

    printf("%d %d\n", e,f );

    hexDump(e, (int) bytes_len);
    hexDump(f, (int) 500);
    hexDump(o, (int) limit);

    return;
}

void hexDump(void *addr, int len) {
    printf("hex address: %d len: %d\n", (uintptr_t) addr, len);

    int i;
    unsigned char buff[17];
    unsigned char *pc = (unsigned char*) addr;

    // Process every byte in the data.
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        // Multiple of 16 means new line (with line offset).

        if ((i % 16) == 0) {
            // Just don't print ASCII for the zeroth line.
            if (i != 0)
                printf("  %s\n", buff);

            // Output the offset.
            printf("%06d ", i);
        }

        // Now the hex code for the specific character.
        printf(" %02x", pc[i]);

        // And store a printable ASCII character for later.
        if ((pc[i] < 0x20) || (pc[i] > 0x7e))
            buff[i % 16] = '.';
        else
            buff[i % 16] = pc[i];
        buff[(i % 16) + 1] = '\0';
    }

    // Pad out last line if not exactly 16 characters.
    while ((i % 16) != 0) {
        printf("   ");
        i++;
    }

    // And print the final ASCII bit.
    printf("  %s\n", buff);
}
```

I set it to dump a large amount of memory from the bytes reference thinking I would find the values in it but it didn't work out that way.

```
hex address: 31519248 len: 4
000000  ff 22 ff 22                                      ."."
hex address: 31519040 len: 500
000000  10 f2 e0 01 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000016  60 a4 b4 1d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  `...............
000032  36 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 26 4a 1b 00 00 00 00  6........&J.....
000048  18 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 d8 e3 01 00 00 00 00  ................
000064  62 5b fa 01 00 00 00 00 88 f1 e0 01 00 00 00 00  b[..............
000080  a0 26 4a 1b 00 00 00 00 10 f2 e0 01 00 00 00 00  .&J.............
000096  c8 41 4a 1b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  .AJ.............
000112  a0 26 4a 1b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  .&J.............
000128  e8 f1 e0 01 00 00 00 00 58 f2 e0 01 00 00 00 00  ........X.......
000144  30 77 f9 01 00 00 00 00 58 b3 f7 6a 07 00 00 00  0w......X..j....
000160  76 f9 f9 01 00 00 00 00 36 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  v.......6.......
000176  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 60 a4 b4 1d 00 00 00 00  ........`.......
000192  70 4a f7 6a 07 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  pJ.j............
000208  b8 48 f7 6a 07 00 00 00 18 f2 e0 01 00 00 00 00  .H.j............
000224  5c 27 4a 1b 00 00 00 00 90 f2 e0 01 00 00 00 00  \'J.............
000240  c8 41 4a 1b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  .AJ.............
000256  00 28 4a 1b 00 00 00 00 e8 f1 e0 01 00 00 00 00  .(J.............
000272  80 f2 e0 01 00 00 00 00 e0 f2 e0 01 00 00 00 00  ................
000288  30 77 f9 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  0w..............
000304  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000320  36 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 70 4a f7 6a 07 00 00 00  6.......pJ.j....
000336  b8 48 f7 6a 07 00 00 00 60 2e f1 6a 07 00 00 00  .H.j....`..j....
000352  a0 f2 e0 01 00 00 00 00 e8 04 4a 1b 00 00 00 00  ..........J.....
000368  10 f3 e0 01 00 00 00 00 90 05 4a 1b 00 00 00 00  ..........J.....
000384  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 38 05 4a 1b 00 00 00 00  ........8.J.....
000400  80 f2 e0 01 00 00 00 00 10 f3 e0 01 00 00 00 00  ................
000416  f0 f3 e0 01 00 00 00 00 da 08 f9 01 00 00 00 00  ................
000432  60 a4 b4 1d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  `...............
000448  70 4a f7 6a 07 00 00 00 b8 48 f7 6a 07 00 00 00  pJ.j.....H.j....
000464  28 3a f7 6a 07 00 00 00 be ba fe ca be ba fe ca  (:.j............
000480  be ba fe ca be ba fe ca 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000496  00 00 00 00                                      ....
hex address: 498377824 len: 54
000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000016  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000032  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000048  00 00 ff 22 ff 22                                ..."."
```

I am reverse engineering how Unsafe_CopyMemory works since it can copy data from a ByteArray into an address.

**Unsafe.copyMemory**

```
UNSAFE_ENTRY(void, Unsafe_CopyMemory(JNIEnv *env, jobject unsafe, jlong srcAddr, jlong dstAddr, jlong size))
  UnsafeWrapper("Unsafe_CopyMemory");
  if (size == 0) {
    return;
  }
  size_t sz = (size_t)size;
  if (sz != (julong)size || size < 0) {
    THROW(vmSymbols::java_lang_IllegalArgumentException());
  }
  void* src = addr_from_java(srcAddr);
  void* dst = addr_from_java(dstAddr);
  Copy::conjoint_memory_atomic(src, dst, sz);
UNSAFE_END

UNSAFE_ENTRY(void, Unsafe_CopyMemory2(JNIEnv *env, jobject unsafe, jobject srcObj, jlong srcOffset, jobject dstObj, jlong dstOffset, jlong size))
  UnsafeWrapper("Unsafe_CopyMemory");
  if (size == 0) {
    return;
  }
  size_t sz = (size_t)size;
  if (sz != (julong)size || size < 0) {
    THROW(vmSymbols::java_lang_IllegalArgumentException());
  }
  oop srcp = JNIHandles::resolve(srcObj);
  oop dstp = JNIHandles::resolve(dstObj);
  if (dstp != NULL && !dstp->is_typeArray()) {
    // NYI:  This works only for non-oop arrays at present.
    // Generalizing it would be reasonable, but requires card marking.
    // Also, autoboxing a Long from 0L in copyMemory(x,y, 0L,z, n) would be bad.
    THROW(vmSymbols::java_lang_IllegalArgumentException());
  }
  void* src = index_oop_from_field_offset_long(srcp, srcOffset);
  void* dst = index_oop_from_field_offset_long(dstp, dstOffset);
  Copy::conjoint_memory_atomic(src, dst, sz);
UNSAFE_END
```

**Unsafe.java**

```
public native void copyMemory(Object srcBase, long srcOffset,
                                  Object destBase, long destOffset,
                                  long bytes);
```

**JNIHandles::resolve**

All this seems to do is cast jobject using *(oop*).  I am not an expert in C and I've never seen that kind of double pointer cast.

```
inline oop JNIHandles::resolve(jobject handle) {
  oop result = (handle == NULL ? (oop)NULL : *(oop*)handle);
  assert(result != NULL || (handle == NULL || !CheckJNICalls || is_weak_global_handle(handle)), "Invalid value read from jni handle");
  assert(result != badJNIHandle, "Pointing to zapped jni handle area");
  return result;
};
```

**index_oop_from_field_offset_long**

The byte_offset can be read/determined by Bits.unsafe().arrayBaseOffset(byte[].class);  For byte[] the value is 16.

```
inline jlong field_offset_to_byte_offset(jlong field_offset) {
  return field_offset;
}

inline void* index_oop_from_field_offset_long(oop p, jlong field_offset) {
  jlong byte_offset = field_offset_to_byte_offset(field_offset);

  if (sizeof(char*) == sizeof(jint))    // (this constant folds!)
    return (address)p + (jint) byte_offset;
  else
    return (address)p +        byte_offset;
}
```

Basically the jbyteArray is cast to *(oop*) then cast to (address) and that is it.  I don't understand why that works but a direct cast to (void *) doesn't.

Comment: _"Basically the jbyteArray is cast to *(oop*)"_. No, the `jobject` is being cast to an `oop*`, which then gets dereferenced, giving you an `oop` (it's unclear to me exactly what an `oop` is).

Comment: The byte[] is cast to jobject which is then cast to oop.  I think oop represents all java objects.

Comment: My point was that `(void*)` is just a cast, while `*(oop*)` is a cast followed by a pointer dereference.

Comment: Do you know what the point of casting to a pointer then dereferencing it is?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Michael for the input.

After two days of fiddling; here is the correct / easy way to do it.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_analyze(
        JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jobject bytes, jint bytes_len, jlong addr,
        jint pos, jint limit) {

    jbyte *elements = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, (jbyteArray) bytes, false);

    char * e = (void *) elements;
    void * f =  *(jobject *) bytes;
    char * o = (void *) (uintptr_t) addr;

    printf("%d %d\n", e,f );

//  printf("address %d limit %d\n", (long) addr, (int) limit);

    hexDump(e, (int) bytes_len);
    hexDump(f, (int) 500);
    hexDump(o, (int) limit);

    //(*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, bytes, elements, 0);
}
```

Output notice that ff 22 ff 22 (the marker we are looking for) starts at position 16 from the dereferenced jobject.

```
34533184 1794590904
hex address: 34533184 len: 4
000000  ff 22 ff 22                                      ."."
hex address: 1794590904 len: 500
000000  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f5 00 00 f8 04 00 00 00  ................
000016  ff 22 ff 22 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ."."............
000032  da 02 00 f8 1d e9 5e ed 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ......^.........
000048  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 41 00 00 f8 13 00 00 00  ........A.......
000064  6a 00 61 00 76 00 61 00 2f 00 6e 00 69 00 6f 00  j.a.v.a./.n.i.o.
000080  2f 00 42 00 79 00 74 00 65 00 42 00 75 00 66 00  /.B.y.t.e.B.u.f.
000096  66 00 65 00 72 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  f.e.r...........
000112  da 02 00 f8 27 e9 5e ed ee 9c 60 df 00 00 00 00  ....'.^...`.....
000128  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 41 00 00 f8 13 00 00 00  ........A.......
000144  6a 00 61 00 76 00 61 00 2e 00 6e 00 69 00 6f 00  j.a.v.a...n.i.o.
000160  2e 00 42 00 79 00 74 00 65 00 42 00 75 00 66 00  ..B.y.t.e.B.u.f.
000176  66 00 65 00 72 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  f.e.r...........
000192  e5 01 00 f8 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000208  66 66 00 f8 8e 43 60 5f 24 e9 5e ed 2e e9 5e ed  ff...C`_$.^...^.
000224  66 f7 5e ed 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  f.^.............
000240  da 02 00 f8 37 e9 5e ed 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ....7.^.........
000256  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 41 00 00 f8 13 00 00 00  ........A.......
000272  6a 00 61 00 76 00 61 00 2f 00 6e 00 69 00 6f 00  j.a.v.a./.n.i.o.
000288  2f 00 42 00 79 00 74 00 65 00 42 00 75 00 66 00  /.B.y.t.e.B.u.f.
000304  66 00 65 00 72 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  f.e.r...........
000320  e5 01 00 f8 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000336  66 66 00 f8 8e 43 60 5f 24 e9 5e ed 3e e9 5e ed  ff...C`_$.^.>.^.
000352  76 f7 5e ed 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  v.^.............
000368  da 02 00 f8 47 e9 5e ed 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ....G.^.........
000384  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 41 00 00 f8 13 00 00 00  ........A.......
000400  6a 00 61 00 76 00 61 00 2f 00 6e 00 69 00 6f 00  j.a.v.a./.n.i.o.
000416  2f 00 42 00 79 00 74 00 65 00 42 00 75 00 66 00  /.B.y.t.e.B.u.f.
000432  66 00 65 00 72 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  f.e.r...........
000448  84 7e 00 f8 ff ff ff ff 80 ab dc 1d 00 00 00 00  .~..............
000464  00 00 00 00 36 00 00 00 f4 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  ....6...........
000480  00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000496  70 e9 5e ed                                      p.^.
hex address: 501001088 len: 54
000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000016  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000032  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000048  00 00 ff 22 ff 22                                ..."."
```

This means that you can access the raw bytes of an primitive array through JNI without using the absurd copy mechanic in GetByteArrayElements; now be aware that this bypasses all sorts of safety checks.